# Thunderbird with lightning not reading valid ics file

Tags: icalendar, thunderbird, lightning

I am writing a program for work that takes all of our ics files from our cal server, merges them into a single ics file, and then places that file on a webserver to be subscribed to.

I have everything working great in the Mac's iCal program and the iPhones subscribe just fine, but Thunderbird with Lightning just chokes and dies. No errors in the Error Console, just nothing.

I have verified that I am fully compliant to the standard, what gives here? Am I missing something special that the wonderful world of open source software has failed to provide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run the ics through a few validators in case you have not:

http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/

http://icalvalid.cloudapp.net/

http://mozilla-comm.github.io/ical.js/validator.html

In Lightning, make sure you are using iCalendar / WebDAV when subscribing to the calendar. You can also use the advanced config editor (`Options -> Advanced -> General -> Config Editor`) to enable the preferences `calendar.debug.log` and `calendar.debug.log.verbose`.

Comment: The Lightning log: you will get the most debug messages if you restart the application, then do whatever you were doing again until you experience the issue. Then check out the error console ("Tools" menu).